# Can't SSH into remote server from Mac

Tags: macos, ssh

A few days ago SSH stopped working on my computer. I'm using Terminal.app on a Mac with the newest version of OS X Lion running on it. This is what running `ssh -vvv myserver` produced:

```
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/bob/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for myserver
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
```

The first thing I thought was that something is up with my server. However, from my MacBook, which is also running Lion, I can `ssh` into my server without a problem. I also tried ssh'ing into other servers from my computer and they don't seem to work either but they seem to work from my macbook.

I think this problem arose when I installed a security update from Apple a couple days ago but I'm not sure.

Additionally, I can `ssh` from my computer onto localhost and to my MacBook so it is just external servers that aren't in my network that I can't seem to `ssh` into. I have already tried multiple SSH programs.

Comment: See what happens when you SSH over another port (say, 44576).

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was all my external connections not on port 80 were being blocked.

Comment: post that as an answer and select it - preferably with the steps you took to find and fix the problem. That way, the question won't periodically be bumped by community, and future users can benefit from the answer (and you can get upvotes!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem was all my external connections not on port 80 were being blocked.

Comment: How do you do this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: It's a firewall configuration problem. Reconfigure your firewall to allow outbound connections on whatever port your connecting to your SSH server.